# How to improve select query speed on Spring with Hibernate and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've a Spring Boot project which I recently managed to deploy on a VPS. I was very surprised when the select queries that were running nearly instantly on my machine slowed down to a crawl there. I knew it would be slower, I just didn't expect by that much.

I've created a test project that reproduces the issue. It selects about 20 000 rows from a table that contains 100 000 rows. It takes about 100 μs to create the query and 0,5–2 s to run the query. I tried to test with 10× more rows, but it took a lot longer than that and eventually threw `OutOfMemoryError`.

I searched around and it seems it shouldn't take this long, specially since it seems to me like not a lot of data. I read and learned about indexes but even a query that is supposed to be a good example of index usage takes a lot of time. Running the query directly in the `psql` console takes about 100 ms without an index and 20 ms with.

If you want to test it, download the [server](https://bitbucket.org/GuiRitter/slowspring20180904server) and the [client](https://bitbucket.org/GuiRitter/slowspring20180904client) projects and follow the instructions there. I started from my real project and removed as much stuff as possible, but left it similar so it can be compared.

---

My VPS specs:

2×2,4 GHz CPU

2 GB RAM

```
uname -a
Linux ampix 2.6.32-042stab127.2 #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 16:41:44 MSK 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Debian Jessie

Java 8 x64

PostgreSQL 9.4

Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE

---

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**: forgot to write about test outside of Spring and forgot that I used 0,8 instead of 0,9 in the select criteria, so the number of selected rows is greater than what I wrote initially.

**Update 2**: using derived query returning `Stream<>` improves performance by a negligible amount.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely running out of RAM, especially with only 2GB. I haven't profiled your query on a Postgres server, but I'd try two things first:

1. Firstly, fix up your query (especially for a simple query like this) to use a derived Spring Data JPA query or even a Spring Data JPQL Query:

   ```
   public interface ScaleTestRepository extends CrudRepository<ScaleTest, Integer>, ScaleTestRepositoryCustom {

       // This is a derived query
       List<ScaleTest> findByWhereTest(BigDecimal whereTest);

   }

   // Or do...

   public interface ScaleTestRepository extends CrudRepository<ScaleTest, Integer>, ScaleTestRepositoryCustom {

       // This is a derived query
       @Query("select scaleTest from ScaleTest as scaleTest where where_test > ?")
       List<ScaleTest> findByWhereTest(BigDecimal whereTest);

   }
   ```

The above will let Spring JPA derive the queries for you, and then you can leverage the following.

2. Secondly, use `Stream` or `Flux` as a return type:

   ```
   Stream<ScaleTest> findByWhereTest(BigDecimal whereTest);

   // Or do

   Flux<ScaleTest> findByWhereTest(BigDecimal whereTest);
   ```

   Either of those will stream (by piecemeal of the `ResultSet`) so that you won't be pulling all of that data into memory and running out your RAM.

Comment: I tried that. In the test projects I provided, it took almost half the time than the first version. Still, I want to believe it's possible to reach at least an order of magnitude of improvement. The same solution barely made a difference in the main project. Oh, and I added missing information in the first post.

Comment: How long does it take to run the same query in Postgres? Have you run an `EXPLAIN` on that query to see what the query plan looks like to see if it's doing any unexpected table scans? We should make sure it's not a SQL bottleneck first before we get to the Java piece.

Comment: 100 ms without an index, 20 ms with. I used `EXPLAIN` previously and saw that it was using an index, though for some reason it's not using it now.